# Autostart no longer working in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, autostart

Since few days my autostart script is no longer invoked. I created a .desktop file within ~/.config/autostart/ that should invoke a script to open Chrome with special tabs.

For some mounth it worked. The invoked script recently got few modification. But now the Chrome does not start anymore after booting. I searched for log entries in syslog, but did not found any hints. I also modified the access rights of the script to 777. And if I invoke the script by commandline, everthing looks fine. No errors.

Where does autostart log to, if there are errors with the script or how can i check, if autostart is working at all? Are there some more things to check?

The system got no other changes. No known system updates or software installations.